# Prevent direct access to uploaded files only for unauthorized users - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I am trying to give direct access to uploaded files only for logged in users in my website for security concerns. I tried [this](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-0/doc/reference/security.html) configuration but it seems to be working on download image.

This is my **Twig file code** where I am showing the image.

```
{% if(req.media!='') %}
      <a href="{% path req.media, 'reference' %}"
      data-fancybox class="fancybox">
       <img src="{% path (req.media), 'reference' %}" alt="" width="70px"
        height="70px"/>
      </a>
{% endif %}
```

configuration for sonata media below.

**Sonata_media.yml**

```
sonata_media:
# if you don't use default namespace configuration
#class:
#    media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
#    gallery: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
#    gallery_has_media: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr it is mandatory to choose one here
default_context: default # you need to set a context
contexts:
    default:  # the default context is mandatory
        download:
            strategy: sonata.media.security.forbidden_strategy
        providers:
            #- sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
            #- sonata.media.provider.youtube
            - sonata.media.provider.image
            - sonata.media.provider.file
            #- sonata.media.provider.vimeo
```

Comment: can you put some snapshot of code? Or explain how you're making image response

Comment: @akbansa added code related to the media. let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed these steps to achieve this requirement.

1. Created a function and added its route in firewall, so anonymous users cannot go to that path.
2. Created a route to set its path.
3. Got media id in the function and did the functionality to return the file.
4. Called the function by its path with parameter `mediaId` instead of calling direct media in twig.

Here is the code.

**security.yml**

```
- { path: ^/user(.*), roles: ROLE_DASHBOARD_USER }
```

**routing.yml**

```
cms_direct_access_uploaded_files:
path:     /user/image-return/{fileId}
defaults: { _controller: CMSFrontUserBundle:Dashboard:DirectAccessUploadedMedia }
```

**Controller**

```
    public function DirectAccessUploadedMediaAction(Request $request,$fileId = null){
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if(!empty($user)){
        $DM = $this->getDoctrineManager();
        $media = $DM->getRepository('ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:Media')->find($fileId);
        if(!empty($media)) {
            $provider   = $this->container->get( $media->getProviderName() );
            $format     = $provider->getFormatName( $media, 'reference' );
            $url        = $provider->generatePublicUrl( $media, $format );
            $ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $returnFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/web'. $url;
            if (file_exists($returnFile)) {
                if($ext == 'pdf'){
                    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
                }else{
                    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                }
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($returnFile));
                readfile($returnFile);
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('Forbidden!');
        }
    }else{
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('Forbidden!');
    }
}
```

**Twig**

```
{{ url('homepage') }}user/image-return/{{ req.media.id }}
```